# POST a json request containing a foreign key and save it with django

Tags: python, json, django

I'm POSTing a json request that I build from an html form:

```
{"discipline":"Mathematiques","date":"2017-12-03"}
```

I'm processing this using this Django view:

```
def cours_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

       data = JSONParser().parse(request)

       serializer = LessonSerializer(data=data)

       if serializer.is_valid():
          serializer.save()
          return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)

       return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

My models.py contains:

```
class Discipline(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Lesson(models.Model):
    discipline = models.ForeignKey(Discipline, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    regular_slot = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My serializers are written as follows:

```
class DisciplineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Discipline
        fields = ('name')

class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    discipline = serializers.RelatedField(source='Discipline', read_only=True);
    class Meta:
       model = Lesson
       fields = ('discipline', 'date', 'regular_slot')
```

However, I have an error saying that:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: cours_lesson.discipline_id

I'm new with Django, and I don't this is the right way to define foreign keys but this is the only way I found.

Comment: are you using `django-rest-framework`? If so, have a look at the [relations documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) for the proper way of handling relation fields in your serializer.

Comment: When do you get the error? Can you post the full traceback? If this happens when you are loading/deserializing json, post the json as well.
This is something that could happen if you try to save a `Lesson` object without assigning a related `Discipline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says "NOT NULL constraint failed". It means that you don't have any value on your database table. You have to set your foreignkey like this.

```
discipline = models.ForeignKey(Discipline, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

After that, migrate your database. Now in your Lesson table, discipline row is filled with Null so that you can set it to another variable later.

Comment: if it gives an error again, add blank=True too. I'm not sure if it works without this.